# Make Text Bolder

Tags: javascript, html, css

It doesn't seem I have a problem but I need to make this more bold

```
.txt {
     font-weight: bolder;
     justify-content: left;
     text-align: left;
     margin-top: 100px;
    /* font-family: 'Redwinger Personal Use', system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    */
     color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
     margin-bottom: 750px;
     margin-left: 25px;
}
```

I tried the property `font-weight:"bolder"` but I want it more bold. Is there any way?

Comment: Nope. Find a font that looks as "bolder" as it's desired. https://fonts.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.txt {
    font-weight: 900;
    justify-content: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    margin-bottom: 750px;
    margin-left: 25px;                                
}
```

You can use font-weight

Comment: i used it i said i want it mooore bolder

Comment: 900 is the highest bold you can get. So what do you want _exactly_? @Ayman